# is there any way we can start the intro.js tour from the step we newly added

Tags: intro.js

Is there any way we can start the intro.js for newly added features only. for new used it will be starting from first setup, but for the user who have already watched till step x for them we can start at from x+1 step.

I tried looking in to documentation but not able to achieve this expected functionality

Answer (score 0):

I did this by putting the IntroJS code inside a function, and called the function if new features were added to my app.

Something like this:

```
function hometour2() {

   introJs().setOptions({
   showProgress: true,
   showBullets: false,
   steps: [{
     element: document.querySelector('#newdiv'),
     intro: 'new features....',
     position: 'right'
   }]

   }).start();
}
```